# Creating Cases in Salesforce from Social Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

how do I know to which Salesforce account Social Studio is linked to? How do I create cases and leads in Salesforce from Social Studio?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add social accounts within Salesforce. Under set up do a quick find for social customer service. Authorize the social account you want to be added there. Once done you need to create engagement macros in social studio and direct to the salesforce org you configured in the previous step. Assuming you are not using social automate in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

After Connection to sales/Service cloud , you will get a option to select org while creating engagement macros. For Every Org of sales/Service cloud, there will be different org id .From there either you can select what u want to  create case or lead or both.[image]